# & operator not working in the isolated scope of directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using & (expression binding) operator in isolated scope of a directive but I am unable to trigger function on the parent controller . There should be output on the console but I am receiving none.

Here in the HTML part:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Directive &</title>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="isolate_scope_&.js"></script>  

    </head>
    <body ng-app="isolate_scope">
        <div ng-controller="isolateScopeController">
          <b>Ctrl Data</b>
          <div ng-repeat="person in persons">
              <p>{{person.name}}</p>
          </div>
          <b>Directive Data</b>
          <div ng-repeat="person in persons">
              <friends frnd="person.name"></friends>
          </div>
          <my-button isolatedFunction="printScopeToFile()"></my-button>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here goes the JS part :

```
  angular.module('isolate_scope', [])
    .controller('isolateScopeController', function($scope){
      $scope.persons = [
                         {
                           name:"tanmay",
                           age:"28"
                         },
                         {
                           name: "James",
                           age:"28"
                         },
                         {
                           name:"Rylan",
                           age:"26"
                         },
                         {
                            name:"Aditya",
                            age:"23"
                         }
                       ];

      $scope.printScopeToFile = function(){
          console.log("printng to file.....");
          for(var i in $scope.persons){
            console.log("Name = " + $scope.persons[i].name + " Age = " + $scope.persons[i].age);
          }
      };
    })
    .directive('friends',function(){
      return {
          restrict :'E',
          template: '<input type="text" ng-model="name">',
          scope :{
            name:'=frnd'
          }
      };
    })
    .directive('myButton',function(){
      return {
          restrict: 'E',
          template: '<button ng-click="isolatedFunction()">callParentfunction</button>',
          scope : {
            isolatedFunction:"&"
          }
      };
    });
```

Fiddle for the same: http://jsfiddle.net/v51kob1q/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute `isolatedFunction` in your `<my-button isolatedFunction...>` directive should need to be `isolated-function`, [`dash-delimited`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#matching-directives) attributes

Comment: Yes, normalization and I wasted so much time on this .

Comment: Can someone please explain why normalisation is done in angular in the first place. What is the need of it ?

Comment: HTML attributes are not case sensitive, but JavaScript is.

Comment: @JackSparrow for the normalisation you can also take a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive